# can we display list-style-type with span text automatically?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a server control that is rendered as a `span`. In its text I have placed `<br>` to display text in multilines.

Next I want to display `list-style` with these `<br>`s. It can be square or disk. Please guide me how it can be done.

Comment: Change your server control to render with `ul`+`li` instead of `span`+`br`.

Comment: If you're using the asp.net [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) control, you can use a [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) control instead then generate the `ul`+`li` as @thirtydot recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to an unordered list:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>in</li>
  <li>multiple</li>
  <li>lines.</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: square;

}
```

OR use block display spans with a background image:

HTML

```
<span class="bg_square">
    Text
</span>

<span class="bg_square">
    in
</span>

<span class="bg_square">
    Multiple
</span>

<span class="bg_square">
    Lines
</span>
```

CSS

```
span.bg_square
{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(path/to/little_square.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Yd3Y2/1/).

Comment: The question didn't make much sense until I fixed the HTML.